# Placing the sun at a specific angle

Tags: scripting, objects

Is there a way to put the sun on a location that is specified by azimuth and altitude, using a script?

Comment: There is the sun position addon that calculates azimuth and elevation from latitude / longitude / time.

Comment: [sun position addon](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Sun_Position) @batFINGER referenced.

Comment: May be interested in this old [BA thread](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?210500-Geographic-Sun-addon!&p=1825148&viewfull=1#post1825148)  and also [this Q&A](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80976/how-to-enable-sun-position-add-on-in-script)

Comment: check this! http://oscurart.blogspot.com.ar/2013/06/blender-script-connect-sun-with-cycles.html This addon is old, but works fine.